# Запустить .exe файл из ресурсов c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня в ресурсах есть исполняемый(.exe)файл. Надо его скопировать на рабочий стол и выполнить.
Вот мой код resource.h

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Used by Resource.rc
//
#define IDR_BIN1                        132

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        133
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32771
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1001
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           101
#endif
#endif
```

и resource.rc

```
#include "resource.h"
IDR_BIN1                BIN     DISCARDABLE     "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\test.exe"
```

и main.cpp

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <Windows.h>

#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>


namespace {
    class Resource {
    public:
        struct Parameters {
            std::size_t size_bytes = 0;
            void* ptr = nullptr;
        };
    private:
        HRSRC hResource = nullptr;
        HGLOBAL hMemory = nullptr;

        Parameters p;

    public:
        Resource(int resource_id, const std::string &resource_class) {
            hResource = FindResourceA(nullptr, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(resource_id), resource_class.c_str());
            hMemory = LoadResource(nullptr, hResource);

            p.size_bytes = SizeofResource(nullptr, hResource);
            p.ptr = LockResource(hMemory);
        }

        auto& GetResource() const {
            return p;
        }
    };

}

int main() {
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Записали в файл, запустили.

Comment: в этом и проблема;/

Comment: В файл не пишется или вы не знаете, как писать?

Comment: не знаю.как писать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример рабочего кода. ( сохраняю дллку из ресурсов т.к. по требованиям системы нужно чтобы все данные были в одной длл).

```
bool writeResourceToFile(HMODULE hLibrary, int resNumber, std::fstream &fileWriter)
{
    HRSRC hRes = FindResource(hLibrary, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resNumber), RT_RCDATA);
    if (!hRes)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        HGLOBAL hResource = LoadResource(hLibrary, hRes);
        if (!hResource)
        {
            //FreeResource(hResource);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            void *text = (LPWSTR)LockResource(hResource);
            if (!text) {
                FreeResource(hResource);
                return false;
            }
            DWORD resourceSize = SizeofResource(hLibrary, hRes);
            fileWriter.write((char*)text, resourceSize);
            fileWriter.close();
            FreeResource(hResource);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

в мейне будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
int main() {
    auto exeFile = std::fstream(...);
    std::string filename = "path\\to\\file.exe";
    if(writeResourceToFile(GetModuleHandle(), IDR_BIN1, exeFile))
        system(filename.c_str()); // ну либо через ShellExecute() если ты не хочешь чтобы окно с интерпретатором появлялось. но для POC-кода привожу так.  
    return 0;
}
```